# Python - Create hierarchy file (find paths from root to leaves in tree represented as table)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given the following unordered tab delimited file:

```
Asia    Srilanka
Srilanka    Colombo
Continents  Europe
India   Mumbai
India   Pune
Continents  Asia
Earth   Continents
Asia    India
```

The goal is to generate the following output (tab delimited):

```
Earth   Continents  Asia    India   Mumbai
Earth   Continents  Asia    India   Pune
Earth   Continents  Asia    Srilanka    Colombo
Earth   Continents  Europe
```

I have created the following script to achieve the goal:

```
root={} # this hash will finally contain the ROOT member from which all the nodes emanate
link={} # this is to hold the grouping of immediate children 
for line in f:
    line=line.rstrip('\r\n')
    line=line.strip()
    cols=list(line.split('\t'))
    parent=cols[0]
    child=cols[1]
    if not parent in link:
        root[parent]=1
    if child in root:
        del root[child]
    if not child in link:
        link[child]={}
    if not parent in link:
        link[parent]={}
    link[parent][child]=1
```

Now I intend to print the desired output using two dict created earlier (root and link). I am not sure how to go about doing this in python. But I know that we could write following in perl to achieve the result:

```
print_links($_) for sort keys %root;

sub print_links
{
  my @path = @_;

  my %children = %{$link{$path[-1]}};
  if (%children)
  {
    print_links(@path, $_) for sort keys %children;
  } 
  else 
  {
    say join "\t", @path;
  }
}
```

Could you please help me achieve the desired output in python 3.x?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see here next problems:

- reading relations from file;
- building hierarchy from relations.
- writing hierarchy to file.

Assuming that height of hierarchy tree is less than default [recursion limit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit) (equals to `1000` in most cases), let's define utility functions for this separate tasks.

### Utilities

1. Parsing of relations can be done with

   ```
   def parse_relations(lines):
       relations = {}
       splitted_lines = (line.split() for line in lines)
       for parent, child in splitted_lines:
           relations.setdefault(parent, []).append(child)
       return relations
   ```
2. Building hierarchy can be done with

   - **Python >=3.5**

     ```
     def flatten_hierarchy(relations, parent='Earth'):
         try:
             children = relations[parent]
             for child in children:
                 sub_hierarchy = flatten_hierarchy(relations, child)
                 for element in sub_hierarchy:
                     try:
                         yield (parent, *element)
                     except TypeError:
                         # we've tried to unpack `None` value,
                         # it means that no successors left
                         yield (parent, child)
         except KeyError:
             # we've reached end of hierarchy
             yield None
     ```
   - **Python <3.5**: extended iterable unpacking [was added with PEP-448](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html?highlight=unpack#whatsnew-pep-448), but it can be replaced with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) like

     ```
     import itertools


     def flatten_hierarchy(relations, parent='Earth'):
         try:
             children = relations[parent]
             for child in children:
                 sub_hierarchy = flatten_hierarchy(relations, child)
                 for element in sub_hierarchy:
                     try:
                         yield tuple(itertools.chain([parent], element))
                     except TypeError:
                         # we've tried to unpack `None` value,
                         # it means that no successors left
                         yield (parent, child)
         except KeyError:
             # we've reached end of hierarchy
             yield None
     ```
3. Hierarchy export to file can be done with

   ```
   def write_hierarchy(hierarchy, path, delimiter='\t'):
       with open(path, mode='w') as file:
           for row in hierarchy:
               file.write(delimiter.join(row) + '\n')
   ```

### Usage

Assuming that file path is `'relations.txt'`:

```
with open('relations.txt') as file:
    relations = parse_relations(file)
```

gives us

```
>>> relations
{'Asia': ['Srilanka', 'India'],
 'Srilanka': ['Colombo'],
 'Continents': ['Europe', 'Asia'],
 'India': ['Mumbai', 'Pune'],
 'Earth': ['Continents']}
```

and our hierarchy is

```
>>> list(flatten_hierarchy(relations))
[('Earth', 'Continents', 'Europe'),
 ('Earth', 'Continents', 'Asia', 'Srilanka', 'Colombo'),
 ('Earth', 'Continents', 'Asia', 'India', 'Mumbai'),
 ('Earth', 'Continents', 'Asia', 'India', 'Pune')]
```

finally export it to file called `'hierarchy.txt'`:

```
>>> write_hierarchy(sorted(hierarchy), 'hierarchy.txt')
```

(we use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) to get hierarchy like in your desired output file)

### P. S.

If you are not familiar with `Python` [generators](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) we can define `flatten_hierarchy` function like

- **Python >= 3.5**

  ```
  def flatten_hierarchy(relations, parent='Earth'):
      try:
          children = relations[parent]
      except KeyError:
          # we've reached end of hierarchy
          return None
      result = []
      for child in children:
          sub_hierarchy = flatten_hierarchy(relations, child)
          try:
              for element in sub_hierarchy:
                  result.append((parent, *element))
          except TypeError:
              # we've tried to iterate through `None` value,
              # it means that no successors left
              result.append((parent, child))
      return result
  ```
- **Python < 3.5**

  ```
  import itertools


  def flatten_hierarchy(relations, parent='Earth'):
      try:
          children = relations[parent]
      except KeyError:
          # we've reached end of hierarchy
          return None
      result = []
      for child in children:
          sub_hierarchy = flatten_hierarchy(relations, child)
          try:
              for element in sub_hierarchy:
                  result.append(tuple(itertools.chain([parent], element)))
          except TypeError:
              # we've tried to iterate through `None` value,
              # it means that no successors left
              result.append((parent, child))
      return result
  ```

Comment: Thanks. I found that this line is giving error: result.append((parent, *element))   SyntaxError: can use starred expression only as assignment target

Comment: Excellent solution. For a python newbie like me, there are lot of things I could pick up and focus from your solution.

Answer (score 1):

With Simple Steps, we can do this,

- **Step 1**: Convert the data to Dataframe,
- **Step 2**: Take a unique element from column 1 which is not in column 2,
- **Step 3**: After taking the unique element from column 1, Convert column 1 as Dataframe,
- **Step 4**: Merge the Dataframes, by using pd.merge(),
      Left data frame as a unique element from column 1, 
      Right data frame as Main Data Which we convert in Step1,
- **Step 5**: Drop_duplicates by all columns

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisites:

1. Data should be in the form of DataFrame,
2. Two Columns should be there.

```
# now we are going to create the function 
def root_to_leaves(data):
    # import library
    import pandas as pd
    # Take the names of first and second columns.
    first_column_name = data.columns[0]
    second_column_name = data.columns[1]
    #XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    # Take a unique element from column 1 which is not in column 2.
    # We use set difference operation.
    A = set(data[first_column_name])
    B = set(data[second_column_name])
    C = list(A - B)
    # m0 means nothing but variable name.
    m0 = pd.DataFrame({'stage_1': C})
    #XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    # first merge data
    data = data.rename(columns ={first_column_name:'stage_1',second_column_name:'stage_2'})
    m1 = pd.merge(m0, data , on = 'stage_1', how = 'left')
    data = data.rename(columns = {'stage_1':'stage_2','stage_2':'stage_3'})
    # count of nan
    count_of_nan = 0
    i = 0
    while (count_of_nan != m1.shape[0]):
        on_variable = "stage_"+str(i+2)
        m2 = pd.merge(m1, data , on = on_variable, how = 'left')
        data = data.rename(columns = {'stage_'+str(i+2)+'':'stage_'+str(i+3)+'','stage_'+str(i+3)+'':'stage_'+str(i+4)+''})
        m1 = m2
        i = i + 1
        count_of_nan = m1.iloc[:,-1].isnull().sum()
    final_data = m1.iloc[:,:-1]
    return final_data

# you can find the result in the data_result
data_result = root_to_leaves(data)
```